# While emitting SIL for 'prepareForSegue'

Tags: swift

I have this compile error :While emitting SIL for 'prepareForSegue' , the same error occurs even if I comment out the function body

my code is like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if( segue?.identifier == "NewDiary")
        {

            let newDiaryController: NewDiaryViewController = segue?.destinationViewController as  NewDiaryViewController;

            newDiaryController.currentDateComp.day +=  dayOffset ;
        }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Xcode beta do you use? Did you put a breaking point over your `prepareForSegue:` method to see if it's actually responsible for your compile time error?

Comment: It looks like you're using an old beta: the prepareForSegue method now takes a non-Optional segue parameter. Try again with Xcode 6 beta 7.

Comment: I also see this problem on a test file using Xcode 7 Beta 5.0. It is a compiler but - source code should not be able to make the compiler crash however that's not going to help with a fix. I've been told by someone else who faces this it was caused by a "long line" in their Swift file. I don't have that but I recommend you try rewriting that function with other logic/layout.